# Chrome debugger doesn't show dynamic class names

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

My Javascript code generates a bunch of ES2015 classes dynamically, including a custom name:

```
const EntitySubclass = class extends Entity {};

Object.defineProperties(EntitySubclass, {
    name: { value: dynamicClassName }
});
```

This works fine in the code itself. `CustomClass.name` returns the expected name. But when shown in the Chrome console or debugger, one of those classes is always called `EntitySubclass`. I also tried this:

```
const obj = { [dynamicClassName]: class extends Entity {} };
const EntitySubclass = obj[dynamicClassName];
```

and this:

```
const obj = {};
obj[dynamicClassName] = class extends Entity {};
const EntitySubclass = obj[dynamicClassName];
```

But that results in the debugger showing me some auto-generated name (`_class3`).

Can this be fixed?

I'm compiling with Babel, and I remember reading somewhere that this behavior depends on the Babel plugins that are used. So here's my Babel config:

```
"presets": [
    "es2015"
],
"plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", { "globals": ["Set"] }],
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-instanceof",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-function-bind",
    "syntax-flow",
    "transform-flow-strip-types"
]
```

Comment: Your first example works for me in Chrome if typed straight into the console.

Comment: @sdgluck Maybe. But I'm compiling this with Babel first, so it's not the same situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "when shown in the Chrome console or debuggger"? Do you mean that if you do `console.log(EntitySubclass)` it prints something like `function EntintitySubClass(){ [...] }`? If so, that's nothing to do with classes; it's just that the name Chrome is showing you there is from the original function or class. Compare (in console): `var x = function(){}; console.log(x.name); console.log(x);`.

Comment: @Bakkot: Yes, that's the problem. I'm looking for a way to make Chrome use the dynamic name I choose in the code. I vaguely remember that my 2nd and 3rd code-fragments should work, but for some babel plugin I'm using. I guess I'll have to use the process of elimination.

Comment: @mhelvens, afaik Chrome is always going to show the name from the original function literal. If you want the name property, you'll have to print it manually.

Comment: @Bakkot: Sure. But how do I define a class with a dynamic original name? I thought my second or third code fragments would do just that. But it appears that they don't. Perhaps something in Babel is responsible.

Comment: @mhelvens, I don't think there's a solution here other than eval. Your second and third code fragments (and indeed first) will dynamically set the 'name' property, but the actual function or class literal is the part beginning 'class ...', i.e. the actual source text, which is not dynamic in the absence of eval. Note that Chrome has native class support, so you can try these things out without Babel.

Comment: @Bakkot: Indeed. I'm using the `Function` constructor now. Pretty safe, the way I'm using it, so that doesn't worry me. I'm just not sure how good browser support is for class literals in `eval`. In any case, if you'd like to write an informative answer in that direction, I'll accept it.